# Globally stable with derivative less than 1

Tags: proof-verification, economics

I am reading Acemoglu's intro to modern economic growth. But I am having trouble understanding his proof to a theorem related with stability. Here is the theorem: 
[image]

And here are some related definitions and theorems:
[image]
[image]

My question lies in his proof to corollary $2.1$. How did he show that the sequence $x(t)$ is monotone and bounded above by $x^*$? I think it is not enough to use that the derivative is less than $1$ and the distance to $x^*$ is shrinking to say $x(t)$ is monotone.

Can someone give me more rigorously written proof?

Thanks!